# Can't boot Windows 10 from CD or from USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, legacy

I just bought a new computer. I installed Windows 10 from CD, and then it started crashing, so I tried to reinstall them, but now I can't get my computer to boot neither from USB nor from CD (I tried many different flash drives and CDs). I also cannot boot Windows 10 from the hard drive. I can enter the BIOS, but that's it. When I try to boot from USB or from CD the Windows logo appears for a few seconds and the the screen turns black.

My hardware:

- Motherboard: Aorus gaming 3
- CPU: i5 9400f
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2x8GB)
- Graphics Card: AMD Radeon 6950

Comment: Can you see the harddrives in the BIOS?

Comment: What happens when you try to boot from hard drive ? Are you able to enter windows recovery environment? How are you making those  windows install USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend you to adjust the boot priority in your BIOS setting to request your DVD drive to boot first, before your HDD. Make sure to insert Windows 10 DVD in your DVD drive.

> How to setup boot order in BIOS?
>
> - In Main tab, set "User SETUP Options" from [Standard] to [Advanced].
> - Go to Boot tab and you can find "Boot Option Priorities".
> - Change the boot order by clicking [+] or [-].

[image]

Once booted, select the "Repair your computer" option to start repairing your Windows 10 PC. You can also use Windows System Restore to rollback your PC to previous working point.

**Problems:**

There are two cases:

- If your PC couldn't boot from DVD, then probably something goes wrong with your BIOS setting and somehow, it couldn't boot as your configuration.
- If your PC can boot from DVD successfully but it doesn't get in function, then I would recommend to check your DVD (or bootable USB flash drive) again.